Access a member of base class if both base and derived classes are nested inside of a template class
template <class T>
struct outer {
  struct base {
    int x;
  };

  struct derived : public base { 
    void func() {
      ++x;
    }
  };
};

This code produces an ‘x’ was not declared in this scope error on the ++x; line
The error disappears if either:

the line template <class T> is removed
++x is replaced with ++base::x or ++this->x
base class is moved outside of outer class
derived class is moved outside of outer class

Why in this specific case do I need to explicitly specify that x is a member of base (or write ++this->x), when I don't have to do it in cases 1, 3 and 4?
The error is present if g++ or clang compiler is used, but not if msvc is used

Lookup works differently with dependent base. Change ++x to ++(this->x). Or as you noticed ++base::x

"The error is present if g++ or clang compiler is used, but not if msvc is used..." MSVC also will give error if you actually use the class template and the member function. Currently you're not using the member function, so the program is IFNDR.

@user12002570 that also seems to fix it. Thanks

@user12002570 I tested it in godbolt, there seems to be no error
https://godbolt.org/z/aPYYcPhs6

It is rejected by all compilers. including msvc as I said. See demo

The demo  you gave works because you're not using /permissive- flag. If you use /permissive- flag, msvc also starts rejecting it. Demo  Always use /permissive- flag with msvc to be sure.
